# How to perform piecewise linear mixed regression with multiple breakpoints in R?

Tags: r, mixed-models, non-linear-regression, nlme, piecewise

I am fitting a piecewise linear mixed regression in R. I know that I can use `lme` from the `nlme` package followed by `segmented` to perform piecewise linear mixed regression. However, upon reading the documentation of the package `segmented`, I noticed that `segmented.lme` could only handle 1 breakpoint, in which I have two (at day 30 and day 90).

For a background, I want to model the mileage of cars (`macars`) at day 0, 30, 90, and 180 (variable `days`), with `age` as a confounder. Note that this model is illustrative and not the real data.

This is my prototype code which uses the `lme` package, before I get confused after reading that `segmented.lme` can only handle 1 breakpoint:

```
fit <- lme(macars ~ days + age, random = ~ days | id, data = df)
summary(fit)
pw.fit <- segmented(fit, seg.Z = ~ days, psi = list(days = c(30, 90)),  random = list(id = pdDiag(~1 + days))
summary(pw.fit)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much

Comment: You can use `bs(knots=c(30,60), degree=1)` to get piecewise linear fits with breaks at 30 and 60.  They aren't "linear cubic splines"; that doesn't make sense. They are just "linear splines".

Comment: @user2554330 ah I see, thanks! In that case for the random effects is `random = ~ days | id` correct? Or should I also introduce the splines there?

Comment: That's a statistical question.  Personally, I think the classical mixed effects models are nonsense, so I'm not the one to ask.  A Bayesian approach is the only one that makes any sense to me.

Comment: In general you should resist the urge to answer your own question/change the answer based on suggestions in the comments.  You could post your solution as an answer, then ask another question about the interpretation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know where the breakpoints are, as suggested by @user255430, you can construct a *linear B-spline basis* (or more specifically ask the model function to construct one for you) via `bs(days, knots = c(30, 90), degree = 1)`.

However, this isn't parameterized the way you think it is.

```r
library(splines)
days <- 1:200
X <- bs(days, knots = c(30, 90), degree = 1)
par(las = 1, bty = "l") ## cosmetic
matplot(X, type = "l")
```

[image]

As you can see, the last section (`days > 90`) is predicted by the sum of the second (red dashed) and third (green dotted) components, not just the third component.

You can use a *truncated power basis* spline instead:

```r
library(cplm)q
## set k=3 to suppress warning
p <- tp(days, knots = c(30, 90), k = 3, degree = 1)
X <- cbind(p$X, p$Z)
matplot(X, type = "l")
```

[image]

However, this is somewhat inconvenient; for only two knots, you can include the components in your model via

```r
~ ... days + I(days*(days>30)) + I(days*(days>90))
```

In general you should at least consider including all of these terms in your random effects components as well.

You can use `emmeans::emmeans` to predict the 'intercept' (predicted value) at different time points, and `emmeans::emtrends` to predict the slope at those time points.

Comment: Thanks! @Ben Bolker so in this case, does `days` become the slope for d0-30, `I(days*(days>30))` for d30-90, and `I(days*(days>90))` for d90-180 ? Is that correct?

#p.s.: I tried including the splines to the random slopes `random = ~ days + I(days*(days>30)) + I(days*(days>90)) | id` but the model failed to converge, so in the end I only included `random = ~ days | id`, will this affect the overall model much?

Comment: Parameterized this way those are the *changes* in the slope at the knots.  It's probably defensible to leave the additional terms out of the random effect; it might be worth trying with `lme4` or `glmmTMB`, which can be slightly more stable.

Comment: 'Parameterized this way those are the changes in the slope at the knots' --> Okay in this case, to obtain the slope for d30-90 I have to add the coefficients of `days + I(days*(days>30))` ?

Comment: Yes ...........

Comment: Thanks! One additional question if you don't mind: is there a way to obtain the intercepts at day 30, 90, and 180, along with the slopes for d0-30, d30-90, and d90-180 along with the CIs and p-values automatically rather than summing them one by one? Thanks in advance

Comment: I didn't show 180, but you can get the idea.

Comment: See edits, I think my suggestion about custom contrasts was wrong.